# css doesn't render correctly on Safari until browser window is resized

Tags: html, css

I've seen similar questions regarding this issue, but they are either related to the mobile version of Safari, or they relate to javascript issues.  Neither of those, I think, are the issue my page is having.

I have a simple paragraph of text that gets centered horizontally using CSS, and the text is responsive so that it scales and wraps within the viewport to always fit and have a specific percentage width of the viewport.

The CSS works perfectly fine in every browser except that in Safari, when the window is narrower than the MAX-width of the paragraph, the paragraph upon page load initially starts out left justified to the viewport.  Only after scaling the viewport manually by even one pixel, or hovering over the menu items which have their own CSS styling, does the paragraph get properly centered.

I am not sure what part of all the code involved I should be including here, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

I've added a link to a codepen I just created with a stripped-down version of the code, but the codepen itself doesn't show the error, so I've attached screen shots in the attached image.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MZEOMQ

[image]

```css
      * {
          margin: 0;
          -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
                  box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      body, html {
          background-color: black;
      }


      .info_wrapperClass {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
            -ms-flex-pack: center;
                justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
        -webkit-box-direction: normal;
            -ms-flex-direction: column;
                flex-direction: column;
        position: relative;
      }
      .infoNoticeParagraphBugreportClass {
        font-size: calc(11px + .5vw);
      }
      @supports ((display: -ms-grid) or (display: grid)) {
        .info_wrapperClass {
          display: -ms-grid;
          display: grid;
          -ms-grid-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
          grid-template-columns: 1fr auto 1fr;
          -ms-grid-rows: auto 1vh auto 1vh auto 1vh auto 1vh auto 1vh -webkit-min-content;
          -ms-grid-rows: auto 1vh auto 1vh auto 1vh auto 1vh auto 1vh min-content;
          grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto -webkit-min-content;
          grid-template-rows: auto auto auto auto auto min-content;
          grid-row-gap: 1vh;
              grid-template-areas:
                                ". info_heading_area ."
                                ". info_notice_area ."
                                ". info_blog_heading_area ."
                                ". info_text_area ."
                                ". separator_line_area ."
                                ". innerwrapper .";
        }
        .info_headingClass {
          -ms-grid-row: 1;
          -ms-grid-column: 2;
          grid-area: info_heading_area;
        }
        .infoNoticeParagraphClass {
          -ms-grid-row: 3;
          -ms-grid-column: 2;
          grid-area: info_notice_area;
        }
        .info_blog_headingClass {
          -ms-grid-row: 5;
          -ms-grid-column: 2;
          grid-area: info_blog_heading_area;
        }
        .infoBlogParagraphClass {
          -ms-grid-row: 7;
          -ms-grid-column: 2;
          grid-area: info_text_area;
        }
      }
      .info_headingClass {
        margin-top: 40px;
      }
      .infoNoticeParagraphClass {
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        max-width: 100vw;
        -ms-flex-item-align: center;
            -ms-grid-row-align: center;
            align-self: center;
        margin-top: 4vh;
      }
      .infoNoticeParagraphClass p {
        margin-left: 5vw;
        margin-right: 5vw;
        max-width: 60em;
        min-width: 20em;
      }
      .info_blog_headingClass {
        -ms-flex-item-align: center;
            -ms-grid-row-align: center;
            align-self: center;
        margin-top: 4vh;
      }
      .infoBlogParagraphClass {
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        max-width: 100vw;
        -ms-flex-item-align: center;
            -ms-grid-row-align: center;
            align-self: center;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-top: 4vh;
      }
      .infoBlogParagraphClass p, h3 {
        margin-left: 5vw;
        margin-right: 5vw;
        max-width: 60em;
        min-width: 20em;
      }
      h1.info_headingClass {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: calc(20px + .5vw);
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        color: white;
      }
      .infoNoticeParagraphClass p {
        font-size: calc(12px + .5vw);
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        color: red;
      }
      h2.info_blog_headingClass {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: calc(18px + .5vw);
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        color: white;
      }
      .infoBlogParagraphClass > h3 {
        font-weight: bold;
        text-decoration: underline;
        text-align: left;
        font-size: calc(12px + .5vw);
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        padding-bottom: .5em;
        color: white;
      }
      .infoBlogParagraphClass > p {
        text-align: left;
        padding-bottom: 1ch;
        line-height: 1.25em;
        font-size: calc(12px + .25vw);
        font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
        color: white;
      }
      @media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
        h1.info_headingClass {
          font-size: 1.75em;
        }
        .infoNoticeParagraphClass p {
          font-size: 1.2em;
        }
        .infoNoticeParagraphBugreportClass {
          font-size: 1.2em;
        }
        h2.info_blog_headingClass {
          font-size: 1.7em;
        }
        .infoBlogParagraphClass > h3 {
          font-size: 1.25em;
        }
        .infoBlogParagraphClass > p {
          font-size: 1em;
        }
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
        .info_headingClass {
          margin-top: 10px;
        }
        .infoNoticeParagraphClass {
          padding-bottom: 10px;
          max-width: 90vw;
          min-width: 60vw;
        }
        .infoBlogParagraphClass {
          padding-bottom: 10px;
          max-width: 90vw;
          min-width: 60vw;
        }
        .infoBlogParagraphClass p, h3 {
          margin-left: 5vw;
          margin-right: 5vw;
          max-width: 50em;
          min-width: 20em;
        }
        h1.info_headingClass {
          font-size: calc(16px + .5vw);
        }
        .infoNoticeParagraphClass p {
          font-size: calc(10px + .5vw);
        }
        h2.info_blog_headingClass {
          font-size: calc(14px + .5vw);
        }
        .infoBlogParagraphClass > p{
          padding-bottom: 1ch;
          font-size: calc(10px + .5vw);
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="pagecontainer">
      <div class="info_wrapperClass">
        <h1 class="info_headingClass">Lorem Ipsum</h1>
        <div class="infoNoticeParagraphClass">
          <p style="color: lightgreen;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Labore possimus ipsam iure repellendus. Odit sit eveniet laboriosam dolores volupt</p>
          <br>
          <p class="infoNoticeParagraphBugreportClass">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Placeat sit, beatae, a neque dolorum temporibus! Corporis aliquam obcaecati rerum praesentium ducimus sequi consectetur, consequuntur, error deserunt ea quos autem similique, sapiente ratione nostrum? Magnam quos obcaecati error rerum ipsa rem itaque ipsam at, natus dicta facilis. Odit provident</p>
        </div>

        <h2 class="info_blog_headingClass">Lorem</h2>
        <div class="infoBlogParagraphClass">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, elit. Ab</h3>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Modi placeat perspiciatis magnam, atque voluptatibus veritatis. Velit inventore doloribus minus, nisi incidunt eum ea beatae possimus, enim ipsam earum laborum nostrum</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores, commodi magnam sequi, sed, velit quos quasi rerum numquam animi nam laboriosam. Voluptas</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Hic similique incidunt quas autem atque, voluptatem quaerat illum possimus vitae nulla. Aliquam ea at iusto aut odit necessitatibus ex exercitationem quae quasi sunt laudantium, ratione voluptatem optio commodi quisquam sequi, molestiae in, vel eum quod eveniet laboriosam tenetur.</p>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Earum voluptates libero totam placeat optio nemo, quos voluptate velit ullam possimusa?</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If this is really true, it sounds like a Safari bug. BTW, what does JavaScript have to do with this?

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I would create a snippet that includes the menu and paragraph HTML and CSS. Keep it simple and clean, but make sure it effectively covers the problem you are encountering.

Comment: @Barmar, I'll try and create a snippet and post it here.  And as to the javascript keyword, there are aspects of the menu that are handled via javascript (e.g. populating the menu text, sub-menu functionality, etc.)

Comment: Can you provide version information about Safari? Also, which platform are you on?

Comment: @AndyHoffman I'm using Safari 11 (13604.1.38.1.6) on MacOS 10.13.  I'm not sure that it should make a difference, but it's inside a virtualbox virtual machine.

Comment: Works fine in my Safari 12.02 on MacOS 10.13.6    Copied your HTML/CSS into a plain index.html, outside of codepen. In my travels I have seen unexpected flex behavior on older (desktop) Safari, while working fine everywhere else.